# Is * an example of a binary operation?

Tags: functions, binary-operations

I think I understand what a binary operation is, but I want to check my understanding with this example to be sure.

First of all, my textbook defines a binary operation in the following way:

Let $A$ be a set. A function from $A \times A$ to $A$ is called a **binary operation** on $A$.

Now for my question:

Define $*$ like this: For real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, $c=a*b$ if $a^2c^2=b^2$. Is $*$ a binary operation? Why or why not?

My initial sense is that $*$ is **not** a binary operation because we can re-arrange the equation as $c = \pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$. So $c$ is **not** uniquely determined by $a$ and $b$. Since a function from $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ must have a unique output, this means that $*$ cannot be properly described by a function and is thus not a binary operation.

Comment: I agree. Binary operations need to be functions, and this is not a function.

Comment: Side comment: even worse, any $c$ at all satisfies this definition of $0*0$.

Comment: Did they specify that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$? I guess this function is a binary operation on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Comment: Great point! It looks like it would be a binary operation for $\mathbb{R_{>0}}$. No domain was specified, but I think it was implied because $a$, $b$, and $c$ are said to be in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also, what would $0*1$ be?

Comment: I don't think $0*1$ has an output at all. It must just be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct. Your expression $a^2c^2=b^2$ does *not* express $c$ in a unique way as a function of $a$ and $b$. Therefore, you don't have a function from $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$, which means that you don't have a binary operation.